# mysqlimport from --secure-file-priv folder, but still got error

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I had set --secure-file-priv as following:

```
mysql> show variables like '%secure%';
+--------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name            | Value    |
+--------------------------+----------+
| require_secure_transport | OFF      |
| secure_auth              | ON       |
| secure_file_priv         | E:\test\ |
+--------------------------+----------+
```

but I got an error like this:

```
D:\Tool\mysql-5.7.17-win32\bin>mysqlimport -u root -p my_test tb < e:test/new/outfile.sql
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1290, The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement, when using table: tb
```

Another error:

```
D:\Tool\mysql-5.7.17-win32\bin>mysqlimport -u root -p my_test tb < e:test\new\outfile.sql
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1290, The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement, when using table: tb
```

what should I do to tackle this?

Comment: add a backslash after `e:`?

Comment: @fancyPants thanks for your idea. it's a pity that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that in my.ini you did not specify the correct directory

## Secure File Priv.

secure-file-priv="F:/directory"